# Problems in plot of $e^x$

Tags: plotting, functions

I try to plot the function e^x in *Mathematica* and I enter the following command:

`Plot[e^x,{x,-1,3}]` but the only thing which appears is a plane with a scale on the y axis from -1 to 1, and on the x axis from -4 to 4.

[image]
I tried attaching a picture of this issue, but since I recently just opened this account, it won't let me. Is there a way to fix this so that the function could be shown?

Comment: Use `E^x` instead.

Comment: Thank you Carl. That worked perfectly.

Comment: Try `Esc+e+e+Esc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start a new cell by typing <kbd>=</kbd>, it will look like this:

[image]

Now just type what you want to do, and the system will try to interpret your commands and show you the proper syntax:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jason.